# Show NSWindow as dropdown from NSStatusItem?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How can I show an NSWindow when clicking on an NSStatusItem, such that it shows over other applications when appearing, but without causing them to lose active status?

I have seen MAAttachedWindow, and it is neat but it does not show on top of other applications unless its own application is active.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would check out this excellent tutorial and sample project:
[Cocoa Popup window in the Status bar](http://blog.shpakovski.com/2011/07/cocoa-popup-window-in-status-bar.html)

That example shows how to "attach" a window to a status bar item, but you could position the window wherever you want. Basically, if you define your app as a `LSUIElement` you can display floating utility windows despite your app never activating or showing a dock icon, and other apps still remain key.

Answer (score 1):

if you use MAAttachedWindow, you can set the winow level as NSStatusWindowLevel. Then it will show on top of other application.